# FreeRadius recognising wrong username

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

Bit of a strange thing that is happenening on our freeradius server. Using laravel, we have a free wifi hotspot login page that authenticates users who have logged in using social logins such as facebook etc. We use the provider ID's of the users as a username for authentification through radius. However the value that we pass the our the radius server and the value that it reads are 2 different values. As an example, we have a form shown below which sends the request to our radius server:

[image: Login Form]

and this is how our radius server recognises the request

[image: Radius request]

As you can see, the value that the radius recognises is -1 to the id being sent, but this results in an auth failure everytime as the radcheck table has the correct Login form ebtry stored.

Comment: You should be using strings, not numbers.

Comment: Yeah we used this as a workaround. But interested to still hear as of why?

Comment: That's a programming question, not an administration question, which is why I sent your question to [so].